# $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$: how to prove it explicitely.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, projective-geometry, projective-space

From general topology, I know that the two mentioned spaces are homeomorphic: one can see $\mathbb{RP}^1$ as $S^1$ equiped with the antipodal quotient relation. Then one finds a (surjective) map from $S^1$ to itself which respects this relation, such as $z\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}\mapsto z^2\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ and conludes by the universal property of the quotien topology (plus the fact $S^1$ is compact Hausdorff) that this mapping induces an homeomorphism $h:S^1/_\sim\cong\mathbb{RP}^1\rightarrow S^1$.

The fact is, to prove that $h$ is a diffeomorphism, as we have not studied something as quotient differentiable structures (by the way, does something like this even exist?) I would need the explixit definition of $h$. I thought of $[x_0:x_1]\in\mathbb{RP}^1\mapsto \frac{(x_0+ix_1)^2}{x_0^2+x_1^2}\in S^1$ but this is not even well defined.

Any help would be great

Comment: So which differentiable structure do you use on $\mathbb{RP}^1$? Or is this point the true core of your question?

Comment: No, maybe I have not been very clear: I mean, I use the 'usual' differentiable structure on $\mathbb{RP}^1$, the one given by the $U_i=\{[x_0,x_1]|x_i\neq0\}$, but I cannot write an explixit diffeomorphism between them. My attempt was to parallel the topological construction of the homeomorphism between the two, but probably I did not get right its explixit expression

Comment: Why do you say that your idea at the end is not well-defined?

Comment: I thought that there were problem with homogeneity, but actually it seems correct!

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta Then you should write an answer to you own question.